# [IOS ]archiving MCOMessageBuilder objects

Tags: mailcore2, mailcore

To support resending of sent failed mails and viewing email body of mails present in outbox, I am planning to persist the MCOMessageBuilder object in sqlite. Since, MCOMessageBuilder is not Nscoding compliant. How to store MCOMessageBuilder in db ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the data of the `MCOMessageBuilder` and using `-[MCOMessageBuilder data]`.

- To resend it, use `-[MCOSMTPSession sendOperationWithData:]`.
- To view it, use `+[MCOMessageParser messageParserWithData:]`.